# How to reuse the same flowShape inside a flow Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a Flow that connects few FlowShapes and it looks like this:

```
def mainFlow: Flow[MyGraphElement, MyGraphElement, NotUsed] = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>

    val someClassifier = builder.add(checkSomething) // FlowShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]
    val filteringRouter = builder.add(partitionBySomething) // UniformFanOutShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]
    val mlRouter = builder.add(partitionBySomethinfElse()) // UniformFanOutShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]
    val publishToSnsFlow = builder.add(publishEvidenceToSns()) // FlowShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]

    val updateTaskStatusDoneFlow1 = builder.add(updateTaskStatus()) // FlowShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]
    val updateTaskStatusDoneFlow2 = builder.add(updateTaskStatus())
    val updateTaskStatusDoneFlow3 = builder.add(updateTaskStatus())

    someClassifier ~> filteringRouter
    filteringRouter.out("case1") ~> publishToSnsFlow ~> updateTaskStatusDoneFlow1 ~> merge
    filteringRouter.out("case2") ~> someDeciderFlow ~> mlRouter

    mlRouter.out("case5") ~> doSomethingFlow ~> updateTaskStatusDoneFlow2 ~> merge
    mlRouter.out("case4") ~> doSomethingElseFlow ~> updateTaskStatusDoneFlow3 ~> merge

    FlowShape(someClassifier.in, merge.out)
})
```

my issue is that I need to call the same method 3 times with different names since FlowShap could only use once inside a Flow...or im missing something, can I do this somehow differently to make it look more elegant? I was referring to updateTaskStatusDoneFlow1/2/3

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about merge first, then run through the flow?

```scala
val someClassifier = builder.add(checkSomething) // FlowShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]
val filteringRouter = builder.add(partitionBySomething) // UniformFanOutShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]
val mlRouter = builder.add(partitionBySomethinfElse()) // UniformFanOutShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]
val publishToSnsFlow = builder.add(publishEvidenceToSns()) // FlowShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]

val updateTaskStatusDoneFlow = builder.add(updateTaskStatus()) // FlowShape[MyGraphElement,MyGraphElement]

someClassifier ~> filteringRouter
filteringRouter.out("case1") ~> publishToSnsFlow ~> merge
filteringRouter.out("case2") ~> someDeciderFlow ~> mlRouter

mlRouter.out("case5") ~> doSomethingFlow ~> merge
mlRouter.out("case4") ~> doSomethingElseFlow ~> merge

merge.out ~> updateTaskStatusDoneFlow

FlowShape(someClassifier.in, updateTaskStatusDoneFlow.out)
```